# mozIndexedDB.open() from a local file (ie. via file:// protocol)

Tags: javascript, firefox4

In FF4 (I'm using MacOS), when calling mozIndexedDB.open() through a local file, an exception is being thrown (IDBDatabaseException.UNKNOWN_ERR)...

The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code." code: "1

It obviously works fine in a normal http/https scenario (ie. the file is being served from a web server).

Is there any workaround or config flag that I can set in FF to be able to utilize indexed DB from a local file?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in Firefox. As of today, there is no solution. Please follow https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643318 for updates on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

And this bug seems to have been fixed with the latest [Firefox nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/).